# After Logout and Login Screen becomes black

Tags: ios, swift

I used User defaults to store Login and Logout Info, After Logging Out When I again login, UI Alters, I tried different solutions but didn't get any proper solution for this.

I tried using if else statement. if the condition is true, show Main Screen else, Show Login Screen.
Here is my code below

For Login I used:

```
@IBAction func signInAction(_ sender: Any) {
    defaults.set(true, forKey: "status")
}
```

For Logout I used:

```
@IBAction func logOutAction(_ sender: Any) {
    defaults.set(false, forKey: "status")
    defaults.synchronize()

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
    self.present(loginVC)
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDel.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
}
```

And in AppDelegate.swift I used:

```
if(status == true){
        let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let mainVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DrawerTabsController") as! DrawerTabsController

        let menuVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DrawerViews") as! DrawerViews

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC)
        appDel.drawerController.screenEdgePanGestureEnabled = true

        appDel.drawerController.mainViewController = mainVC
        appDel.drawerController.drawerViewController = menuVC

        appDel.window?.rootViewController = appDel.drawerController
        appDel.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else {
        let rootVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController

//ViewController is LoginVC

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = rootVC
    }
```

Navigation Bar UI Changes.

[image]

Comment: try self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible() in you else part.

Comment: Tried, still getting the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is not for your code, I just shared my flow which is I used in whole my iOS application. It is just like a magic.

I think you need to change your app flow.

First open your dashboard screen, In dashboard screen check login status in `viewDidAppear` method and present login screen with navigation (Navigation if you want to navigate register screen or forgot password screen from login screen).

In Login screen.
After call api and get success login status just dismiss login screen (If you present navigation then just dismiss navigation controller).

Don't need to change your root view controller in this flow, It is very simple flow.